# tried to upload my node.js app to heroku,it says Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch, Process exited with status 137

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I tried to upload my node.js app to heroku, it says error is Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch, Process exited with status 137,how do I fix this 
here is my app.js

```
require('dotenv').config();

const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const engine = require('ejs-mate');
const path = require('path');
//conscd t favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const User = require('./models/user');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
//const seedPosts = require('./seeds');
//seedPosts();

//require routes
const index = require('./routes/index');
const posts = require('./routes/posts');

const app = express();

console.log(process.env.DATABASEURL);
//connect to database
var url = process.env.DATABASEURL || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/transfed'
mongoose.connect(url,{
    useNewUrlParser: true ,
     useUnifiedTopology: true,
     useCreateIndex: true
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
    console.log("we're connected!");
});

var store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: 'process.env.DATABASEURI',
  collection: 'mySessions'
});

// Catch errors
store.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

i figured it might be from the bin file but i cant find the error.
heres what my bin file looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('myapp:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

I used express generator to generate the skeleton of my app and am new to programming, what do I have to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would try without the `normalizePort()` function. This is what I am using and it works perfectly:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

I am not sure where you found your code but I would test with a [simple example from the official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs?singlepage=true) to make sure it works well:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

Finally, I would also check the `Procfile` and make sure it contains the [right command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).

Comment: i used express generator to generate the skeleton of my app, the simple example from heroku works fine and deploys normally, it still give me the same error when am trying to deploy to heroku